# Application of clustering in segmentation and reduction

Tags: matlab, compression, cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I have a multi dimensional time series data that are the features for action recognition. I have 20 variables representing 3D joint positions, quaternion values, mean, euclidean distance between joints. I have applied kmeans clustering with k=4. After clustering, I want to combine co-occuring cluster id's together such that the data points corresponding to them are also clubbed together by that cluster id. For instance, considering the following cluster indices for 10 data samples,

```
IDX = [1 1 2 1 3 3 3 2 2 4]'
```

Let the data be the following where A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H are the 3 feature varaibles where (A-C) represents (x,y,z) coordinate of a particular joint, and D represents the euclidean distance of the joint relative to the head,(E-H) are the quaternion value of the joint. Let the numeric values be the elements. `Data =`

```
A   B   C   D    E   F    G   H
a1  b1  c1  d1   e1  f1   g1  h1
a2  b2  c2  d2   e2  f2   g2  h2
a3  b3  c3  d3   e3  f3   g3  h3
a4  b4  c4  d4   e4  f4   g4  h4
a5  b5  c5  d5   e5  f5   g5  h5
a6  b6  c6  d6   e6  f6   g6  h6
a7  b7  c7  d7   e7  f7   g7  h7
a8  b8  c8  d8   e8  f8   g8  h8
a9  b9  c9  d9   e9  f9   g9  h9
a10 b10 c10 d10  e10 f10  g10 h10
```

Then, the result will be a reduced vector (compressed version of the data) where first 2 rows of data will be represented by the cluster id 1, 3rd row of data by cluster id 2, 4th row = 1, fifth, sixth and 7th rows will be combined and represented by 3,8th&9th row by 2 and last row by 4. Thus, the final data representation becomes a compressed string whose dimensionality and length is also reduced : `Compressed_Data = [1 2 1 3 2 4]'` . How do I do this mapping and conversion? Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's not clear what you are doing.  Have you tried any coding for the problem and can you show an example of how to get the output from the input?  Shouldn't the second to last row of your output be 2 instead of 1?

Comment: That's fine.  I'm wondering about the output, if that's an error in `Compressed_Data`

Comment: I'm asking about the second to last element (`Compressed_Data(end-1)`).  Why is that 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compress your index array, `IDX`, you could try the following:

```
a = IDX; % for clarity, use a different variable, a
a(find(diff(IDX)==0)+1) = []; % remove repeating elements
Compressed_Data = a;
```

Alternatively,

```
Compressed_Data = IDX([1; find(diff(IDX(:))~=0)+1])
```

Please let me know if this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: @SrishtiM - The first line of code is just a starting point, not the results.  Try running _both_ lines of code. When you say "I am merging & representing first 2 rows of IDX into 1 row & representing it by symbol 1.This in turn will make the first 2 rows of my original data represented by symbol 1", that explains how you get `Compressed_Data(1)` from `IDX(1:2)`.  This is what my posted code does.  Try running the second, alternate solution.  It also takes any co-occurring symbols in IDX and compresses them.  Also, please help me understand how you got `Compressed_Data(end-1)` equal to `1`.

Comment: Great!  I would appreciate an upvote since you found it helpful, and I stuck with it.  ;)  The `find` operation you mention gives the indices of the repeated values by comparing adjacent values for equality.  I would suggest timing both options to see which one is fastest, but I would guess the second one. I have no links, sorry.